# The difference between ‘He had only been there for a few minutes’ and ‘He had been there only for a few minutes.’?

Tags: word-usage

The difference between ‘He had only been there for a few minutes’ and ‘He had been there only for a few minutes.’ ?

The ‘only’ was put in different position.

Answer (score 1):

By moving the "only" past the "been there" part, it adds emphasis to the "few minutes"

Two situations would illustrate the difference in usage:

1. A man is standing in a bus line. He had only been there for a few minutes, when the bus arrived.
2. A man is cheered by seeing the bus arrive; he had been there only for a few minutes.

Personally, I think the first one is more plebian and boring, something you'd see in a newspaper.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant difference in meaning, and both are correct.

> He had only been there for a few minutes

emphasizes the shortness of the time more strongly than the other version.

By the way, "for" can be omitted (elided) in either case

> He had only been there a few minutes
>
> He had been there only a few minutes

The meaning is unchanged, and this is perhaps more likely from a native speaker, although the version with 'for' would be more likely in semi-formal or formal writing.

Comment: I see no difference in emphasis here. — Attaching *only* to the minutes, rather than to the verb, is sometimes better to avoid ambiguity, though no such ambiguity is possible in this sentence.

Comment: @Anton It is a subtle point, and I might be wrong. Placing "only" near the start of the sentence, and attached to the main verb, seems to me to stress "only" a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are more options.

The ones you proposed:

1. He had only been there for a few minutes.
2. He had been there only for a few minutes.

but also

3. He had been there for only a few minutes.

I disagree with the other answers (so far), which seem to suggest choices #1 and #2 are equally 100% correct, or even that #2 is better.  In my personal opinion (which could very well be mistaken) Choice #1 is idiomatic, colloquial, and right.  Choice #2 sounds somehow awkward or stilted, as if being spoken by a non-native speaker.  Choice #3 is acceptable, especially if followed by more information, such as:

3a. He had been there for only a few minutes, when he realized the bus had probably already left.

Comment: I should have written your #3 as my number 2. I agree it is more natural. I would change my answer, but the time continuum <geustures at everything> ...